# Current Sensor ACS758 + Arduino

Tags: arduino

I'm Using Arduino and current sensor Acs758-050B to get current reading on serial monitor but it gives inaccurate measures not similar to the load
Acs758 Datasheet [text](https://www.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/pdf/480257/ALLEGRO/ACS758LCB-050B-PFF-T.html)
I use this code from here [text](http://robojax.com/learn/arduino/?vid=robojax-allegro_ACS758)
But it gives wrong measures in the serial monitor

```
  
 */
#define VIN A0 // define the Arduino pin A0 as voltage input (V in)
const float VCC   = 5.0;// supply voltage 5V or 3.3V. If using PCB, set to 5V only.
const int model = 2;   // enter the model (see below)

float cutOffLimit = 1.00;// reading cutt off current. 1.00 is 1 Amper

/*
          "ACS758LCB-050B",// for model use 0
          "ACS758LCB-050U",// for model use 1
       
sensitivity array is holding the sensitivy of the  ACS758
current sensors. Do not change.          
*/
float sensitivity[] ={
          40.0,// for ACS758LCB-050B
          60.0,// for ACS758LCB-050U

         }; 

/*         
 *   quiescent Output voltage is factor for VCC that appears at output       
 *   when the current is zero. 
 *   for Bidirectional sensor it is 0.5 x VCC
 *   for Unidirectional sensor it is 0.12 x VCC
 *   for model ACS758LCB-050B, the B at the end represents Bidirectional (polarity doesn't matter)
 *   for model ACS758LCB-100U, the U at the end represents Unidirectional (polarity must match)
 *    Do not change.
 */
float quiescent_Output_voltage [] ={
          0.5,// for ACS758LCB-050B
          0.12,// for ACS758LCB-050U
           
          };
const float FACTOR = sensitivity[model]/1000;// set sensitivity for selected model
const float QOV =   quiescent_Output_voltage [model] * VCC;// set quiescent Output voltage for selected model
float voltage;// internal variable for voltage
float cutOff = FACTOR/cutOffLimit;// convert current cut off to mV

void setup() {
    //Robojax.com ACS758 Current Sensor 
    Serial.begin(9600);// initialize serial monitor
  
}

void loop() {
  //Robojax.com ACS758 Current Sensor 
  float voltage_raw =   (5.0 / 1023.0)* analogRead(VIN);// Read the voltage from sensor
  voltage =  voltage_raw - QOV + 0.007 ;// 0.007 is a value to make voltage zero when there is no current
  float current = voltage / FACTOR;
  if(abs(voltage) > cutOff ){
    Serial.print("V: ");
    Serial.print(voltage,3);// print voltage with 3 decimal places
    Serial.print("V, I: ");
    Serial.print(current,2); // print the current with 2 decimal places
    Serial.println("A");
  }else{
    Serial.println("No Current");
  }
  delay(500);
}
```

I expect ampere same as load

Comment: AC or DC? for AC you have to sample at least one cycle and calculate the RMS value